# Primefaces wizard - Cancel and reset wizard

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wizard

How do you close and reset a wizard without the backing bean being called?

I have tried this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="PF('wizard').loadStep(PF('wizard').cfg.steps[0], true);"
oncomplete="PF('wizard').hide(); />
```

I have also tried to call

```
PF('wizard').loadStep(PF('wizard').cfg.steps[0], true);
```

in the console, but it always calls the backing bean.

My problem is that the backing bean is always called, and when I open the wizard again, it is not on the first page.

Comment: do you call your backing bean from somewhere ?!?

Comment: Backing bean is called because you are clicking on the p:commandButton. Add return false; to the onclick to avoid the backing bean request.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Is there any way to "reset" the wizard on close?

Comment: Sorry, i have never worked with the wizard component. Instead i have used only the p:steps component and implemented my own wizard paginaton logic.